# What is the record for siblings from a single family in a film?

Tags: casting

I was wondering if there's a movie that can beat *[Scrooged](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096061/?ref_=ttfc_fc_tt)* (1988) in terms of *sibling* actors starring in it - it starred **[Bill Murray](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000195/?ref_=tt_ov_st)**, **[Brian Doyle-Murray](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0236519/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t20)**, **[Joel Murray](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0615063/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t66)** and **[John Murray](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0615066/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t13)**.

*To narrow it: (human) actors, not people appearing as themselves (eg, documentary); and I'm looking for the longest list of siblings from one family, not groups of different siblings.*

Comment: Does [Inside The Osmonds](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0269677/combined) count? ;)

Comment: No - I'm talking about normal humans lol.

Comment: They're not *actors* though are they? Aren't they being  themselves?

Comment: Ah, skipped that word. ;) Western cinema only?

Comment: Wondering if [the Arquettes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arquette_family) ever were in a movie together. Don't think so, however.

Comment: Or the Baldwins, for that matter, though I doubt their egos can fit in one studio. ;)

Comment: And of course, the Marx brothers (minus Gummo) would equal the number in the question. The 4 of them appeared together in at least 5 films.

Comment: There are of course the scenes from movies re-enacted by the siblings in [The Wolfpack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wolfpack).

Comment: Doesn't beat the Wayans, but the Cusacks are known for being in a lot of movies together.  They don't appear to have gotten all five siblings (John, Joan, Ann, Bill, and Susie) into one movie, but four of them (all but Susie) were in [Grosse Pointe Blank](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119229/) together.

Comment: @talemyn Ja I own and love that. Also High Fidelity. I think J & J have been in a few together. Those two are my faves

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The Wayans family is usually a good source for this sort of thing. [I'm Gonna Git You Sucka](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0095348/combined) (1988) stars no less than **6 siblings**: Keenen Ivory Wayans, Damon Wayans, Kim Wayans, Nadia Wayans, Marlon Wayans and Shawn Wayans.

[And as a corollary, [Dance Flick](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1153706/combined) (2009) must be holding some sort of record too. I've counted at least 11 different members of the Wayans family in the cast and crew.]

Comment: Six doubles four, lol? If no one can beat this number I'll green tick it.

Comment: Oh wait, just saw you were replying to the other poster ...

Comment: No, I thought your question had 3 siblings, sorry. Whoops (fixed).

Comment: Six is the number to beat!

Answer (score 37):

The film '101 Dalmations' featured no less than 200 dogs from around a dozen trainers. Several of the trainers provided dogs from **litters of up to 13 dogs, all of whom would have been siblings (e.g. brothers and sisters).**

It may interest you to know that they needed this number of dogs because no single dog could be used for more than 2-3 weeks because they grew too fast and [stopped looking cute](http://www.filmscouts.com/scripts/matinee.cfm?Film=101-dal&File=animals) and that even those from the same litter required the services of a dedicated makeup artist who was on hand to make the dogs all look alike!

---

You may also want to consider "[Phase IV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_IV)". The film dealt extensively with a colony of *thousands* of ants, all of whom would have been sisters.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure these count as actors compared to documentary.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann - The [American Human Society](http://www.americanhumane.org/assets/pdfs/animals/pa-film-guidelines.pdf) would beg to differ. Since this is a feature film with **staged scenes**, they clearly fall under the definition of "Animal actors".

Comment: Too late to change it, but of course I meant humans.

Comment: @DanielStowers - Gotta be precise :-)

Comment: Sure. "No tree hugging, Medium-watching, patchouli chomping, PETA-supporting individuals need apply."

Answer (score 19):

The 1980 western The Long Riders stars [**four sets of actor brothers**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Long_Riders#Cast) as the real-life sets of brothers:

> - The Keaches: Jesse James (James Keach) and Frank James (Stacy Keach)
> - The Carradines: Cole Younger (David Carradine), Jim Younger (Keith Carradine) and Bob Younger (Robert Carradine)
> - The Quaids: Ed Miller (Dennis Quaid) and Clell Miller (Randy Quaid)
> - The Guests: Charley Ford (Christopher Guest) and Robert Ford (Nicholas Guest)
>
> It also features an uncredited appearance by Ever Carradine, daughter
>   of Robert Carradine and niece to David and Keith Carradine.
>
> Additionally James Keach's son, Kalen Keach, is cast as Jesse James's
>   son Jesse E. James.

source: Wikipedia

Comment: How the HELL did I not know about this film?? I just WISHLISTED it on Ebay. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Wait. Keith Carradine and David Carradine are brothers?! Somehow I never made the connection.