# Most direct family members in a film?

Tags: casting

Which film has the most actors that are direct family members?

To be fair, lets exclude non-significant crowd roles.

Comment: Isn't this basically a dupe of http://movies.stackexchange.com/a/43609/13595 ?

Comment: Although I have not seen that question, here I ask about FAMILY MEMBERS and not SIBLINGS.

Answer (score 3):

*Dance Flick* was a 2009 spoof that had 6 Wayans family acting and a seventh directing: Damon, Shawn, Marlon, Kim, Craig, and Keenan Ivory; it was directed by Damien Dante.